# Loop through axios data and perform another axios request and concat the two results into one JSON

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

So I have an axios request to a rapid API, my function looks like this...

```
//Initialize the lookup API that utalizes rapidAPI to get breach data
app.get("/lookup/:email/:function", (req, res) => {
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/",
    params: { func: `${req.params.function}`, term: `${req.params.email}` },
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": `${config.RAPID_API_KEY}`,
    },
  };
    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        res.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  } 
});
```

The `res.json(response.data);` will show on the page a result like this:

```
{
  "disclaimer": "This data is aggregated from BreachDirectory, HaveIBeenPwned, and Vigilante.pw.",
  "info": "For full source info, request e.g. https://breachdirectory.tk/api/source?name=Animoto",
  "sources": [
    "123RF",
    "500px",
    "Adobe",
    "AntiPublic",
    "Apollo",
    "Bitly",
    "Dave",
    "Disqus",
    "Dropbox",
    "ExploitIn",
    "ShareThis",
    "Straffic",
    "Ticketfly",
    "Tumblr",
    "VerificationsIO"
  ]
}
```

I want to loop through everything in the "sources" array, and call upon the following:

[https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/[ITEM]](https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/%5BITEM%5D)

So, the first one will call upon https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/123RF

```
So each result from that call will look like this:

{
  "Name": "123RF",
  "Title": "123RF",
  "Domain": "123rf.com",
  "BreachDate": "2020-03-22",
  "AddedDate": "2020-11-15T00:59:50Z",
  "ModifiedDate": "2020-11-15T01:07:10Z",
  "PwnCount": 8661578,
  "Description": "In March 2020, the stock photo site <a href=\"https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/popular-stock-photo-service-hit-by-data-breach-83m-records-for-sale/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">123RF suffered a data breach</a> which impacted over 8 million subscribers and was subsequently sold online. The breach included email, IP and physical addresses, names, phone numbers and passwords stored as MD5 hashes. The data was provided to HIBP by <a href=\"https://dehashed.com/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">dehashed.com</a>.",
  "LogoPath": "https://haveibeenpwned.com/Content/Images/PwnedLogos/123RF.png",
  "DataClasses": [
    "Email addresses",
    "IP addresses",
    "Names",
    "Passwords",
    "Phone numbers",
    "Physical addresses",
    "Usernames"
  ],
  "IsVerified": true,
  "IsFabricated": false,
  "IsSensitive": false,
  "IsRetired": false,
  "IsSpamList": false
}
```

I want to make my res.json send over a JSON string that will have all the sources still there, along with the "Title","Description", and "LogoPath" from the API calls that it pulled for each one of the sources. So I will have a JSON string with the sources along with the title of each source, description of each source, and LogoPath of each source.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create an array of promises and run with `Promise.all`

```js
app.get('/lookup/:email/:function', async (req, res) => {
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/',
    params: { func: `${req.params.function}`, term: `${req.params.email}` },
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': `${config.RAPID_API_KEY}`,
    },
  };

  axios.request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      const requestTasks = [];

      for (let item of response.data.sources) {
        const itemOption = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: `https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/${item}`,
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
          }
        };

        requestTasks.push(axios.request(itemOption));
      }

      return Promise.all(requestTasks);
    })
    .then((responseList) => {
      for (let response of responseList) {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

2. Use `async/await (promise)` and `for await` for get data from for loop

```js
app.get('/lookup/:email/:function', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/',
      params: { func: `${req.params.function}`, term: `${req.params.email}` },
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': `${config.RAPID_API_KEY}`,
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.request(options);
    for await (let item of response.data.sources) {
      const itemOption = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/${item}`,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      };
      const itemResponse = await axios.request(itemOption);
      console.log(itemResponse.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: lookupData is not defined

Comment: I don't use `lookupData` variable in this code, Are you sure this snipped code has a problem?

Comment: Ahh.. Wong one. Okay, so I changed       console.log(itemResponse.data);

to       res.send(itemResponse.data);

And I get his with a Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client 

error. But it does print out the first value

Comment: What's the best way if I want it to output a JSON string with all that data?

Because even the console.log doesn't return proper json

Comment: UPDATE: Both solution 1 and 2 return an HTTP headers sent error.

Answer (score 0):

This how I managed to make it works.

> first: I didn't had any APi key (and didn't want to register to get one) So i used a dummy Api.
> although the logic stay the same as i have tested the result.
>
> second i kept all your initial url just next to the one i used.so you can easily switch back to your original url.
>
> finally i put comment to any critical part, and i named variable in a
> way that they almost describe what they do.
> so you can copy past test it to understand my logic then adapt it to your use case.

here the code

```
// make sure to replace /lookup by  /lookup/:email/:function after testing my logic
            
        app.get('/lookup', async (req, res) => {     
          
          try {
          // in this options no change just switch back to your url
          var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
            //  url: "https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/",
            // params: { func: `${req.params.function}`, term: `${req.params.email}` },
            // headers: {
            //   'x-rapidapi-host': 'breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com',
            //   'x-rapidapi-key': `${config.RAPID_API_KEY}`,
            // },
          };
        // here you get all your sources list (in my case it an array of object check picture 1 bellow)
          const allSources = await axios.request(options)
          console.log(allSources.data);
        
        // because my dummy api response is a huge array i slice to limited number
          const reduceAllsource = allSources.data.slice(0,5);
          console.log(reduceAllsource);
        
          // note here you need to replace reduceAllsource.map by allSources.data.map 
          // because you don't need a sliced array
          
          const allSourcesWithDetails = reduceAllsource.map(async (_1sourceEachtime)=>{
            // here you can switch back to your original url 
            // make sure to replace [ITEM] by ${_1sourceEachtime}
            const itemOption = await axios({
              method: 'GET',
              url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${_1sourceEachtime.id}/photos`,
              // url:`https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breach/[ITEM]`
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              }
            });
            // this the place you can mix the 2 result.

            const mixRes1AndRes2 ={
              sources:_1sourceEachtime.title,
              details:itemOption.data.slice(0,1)
            }
            
            return mixRes1AndRes2;
          })
        // final result look like the picture 2 below
        
        finalRes= await Promise.all(allSourcesWithDetails);
        return res.status(200).json({response: finalRes});   
        
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }      
        });
```

Picture 1

[image: Response of to the albums endpoint]

Picture 2

[image: final res]

Comment: Had to tailor it for my API calls, but it worked!

Comment: Nice ! that's why over commented it.  You can mark it as the Answer. Happy coding

Comment: @JoshHolly if it solved your question, you can mark this as the answer